# Read Hyper-V snapshots

Tags: snapshot, hyper-v

We can take VSS based snapshot of Hyper-V VM using `WMI` `CreateSnapshot()` API  provided by `Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService`.
But there is no API provided to read the snapshot data.
Please suggest the ways to read Hyper-V snapshot data for backup purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many details which you can leverage for your backup purpose.

The [Msvm_VirtualSystemSnapshotService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850259%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class contains the following properties:

Description, DetailedStatus, OperatingStatus, OperationalStatus, PrimaryStatus, StatusDescriptions  etc.

Comment: Ya. But there has to be some way to mount and read the snapshot disk data

Comment: Yes there are. Read the `Msvm_ImageManagementService` . After mount you can read the disk.

  `Set inParam = imageManagementService.Methods_("Mount").InParameters.SpawnInstance_()
    inParam.Path = path`


 `Set outParam = imageManagementService.ExecMethod_("Mount", inParam)`

Comment: Let me know if you want to know how to mount using ImagemanagementService.